# Killing user session when idle in 30 minutes - java based

Tags: java, eclipse, session, coding-style

Good day!

I am developing a system.
A java based web application.
From the system requirement, a session have to be killed when the user is found to be idle within 30 minutes.

What is the easiest way to do this?

I've read using setMaxInactiveInterval() of HttpSession but don't know how to implement this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: which servlet container are you using?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)  What is your question?

Comment: Great you can easily kill the session when the user is idle for 30 mints

Comment: i haven't tried doing this. because i cannot find a sample in coding it. thank you..

Comment: @asifsid88  *"is idle for 20 mints"*  Are they chocolate mints?  Count me in!

Comment: You have described the scenario very vaguely. You need to be more specific about the technology you're using.

Comment: *"i cannot find a sample in coding it"*  What search terms were used?

Comment: @AndrewThompson, SuKu, asifsid88, AmithKoujalgi thank you :)

Comment: @SuKu i'm using tomcat

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways of doing it:

1) web.xml

```xml
<web-app ...>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
</session-config>
</web-app>
```

Here you can specify timeout in minutes.

2) In Servlet

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
session.setMaxInactiveInterval(30*60);
```

Here you specify session timeout in seconds.

**Note**: Important difference between `web.xml` and `setMaxInactiveInterval`. In `web.xml` you specify it in minutes where as in `setMaxInactiveInterval`, you specify it in seconds, so you need to convert it into minutes, if you want it in minutes.

Answer (score 0):

You can set in web.xml:
`<session-config>`
`<session-timeout>30</session-timeout>`
`</session-config>`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using tomcat as you web container to execute you servlet or jsp applications then  please locate the following section in `[Tomcat_home]/conf/web.xml`:

```
<session-config>
  <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

The timeout value is specified in minutes.
Restart Tomcat after modifying the file, so the changes can take effect.

`OR`

You can change the session expiry to a specific project under the tomcat manager page(`http://localhost:8080/manager/html`) as shown in the image below. The default time out is 30 minutes. You can provide the value in minutes.

[image]